# I am after a better specification of fuse than is on the board of a daikin split air conditioner

Tags: fuses

I picked up a couple of scrap daikin split Ftxs60bvmb
The fuse on the control board is dead but it only says 3.15a 250v
Is this a ceramic slow blow/ anti surge or a fast blow fuse?

Comment: In general, a device that contains one or more (large) motors would use a time-delay / slow-blow fuse.  The largest current-consuming device in your air conditioner is the compressor motor.

Comment: Even the service manual does not reveal the fuse type. Besides, fuses don't blow up themselves - most likely there is a fault in some other component and if you don't fix that first it will just blow up the new fuse immediately.

Comment: Colin Ellis - Welcome :-) Since you say that the fuse is dead (and therefore you have the fuse), please edit the question and add photos of the fuse body and the end caps of the fuse, showing all markings. It could be that there is a clue there, which someone here will recognise. Failing that, there may be an alternative approach, depending on what markings there are on the fuse. (And as others have mentioned, fuses rarely blow for no reason (except old age or being underspecified in the first place), so you should be prepared for there to be a currently-unknown underlying fault.)

Comment: It looks like a slow blow ceramic but it's soldered into the board and back on the wall at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check the electronics before replacing the fuse. Why is the fuse blown?
Beside that question:

Normally, control boards or electronics (without transformers or motors) are protectet with fast blowing fuses.
Here I would use (and it is not a big problem to use) a fast blowing fuse.

In the manual, the manufacturer only describes the fuse with 3.15 A only, and if you want to be really sure you have to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You should have made this a comment instead.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Edited it.

Comment: And how do you know it is not a big problem to use a fast blowing fuse, if you don't know what the original fuse type is?

Comment: If you compare the characteristics of the different types of fuses, you will see it. And in the case of a control board, you will certainly not choose line protection as a fuse measure.